# If a function is differentiable then will it always be the case that I can produce from it a gradient vector field?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> If a function is differentiable then will it always be the case that I can produce from it a gradient vector field?

I don't guess there is anymore but that.   Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "product from it"?  Are you asking if a differentiable function has a gradient?

Comment: Yes I am asking this....I seem to have made a typo....should say "produce" not "product"

Comment: What kind of function are you talking about? Scalar function? Vector function?

Comment: A vector function.  There is a reason I ask. This question came up while working backwards with vector fields that are not  gradient vector fields. An example is  F= <-y,x>  Does it work the other way around and if so does that mean that all inexact differentials are undifferentiable.  sorry for spelling...

Answer (score 1):

In dimension 1, yes: A differentiable function is continuous, so it has an antiderivative.

In higher dimensions, no: In order to be [conservative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field), your function must be irrotational, having a zero exterior derivative. (This function is trivially satisfied in dimension 1.)

Comment: Is this an answer to the question that was asked?  You're saying not every continuous vector field is the gradient of a function.  The OP seems to be starting with a function and asking whether it has a gradient.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Good point, on a second reading, it looks like I did misinterpret the question. On the other hand, I'm still not sure what the question is really concerned about.